# Continuity of multivariable functions

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, continuity, normed-spaces

I have a question regarding norms on $\Bbb R^{n}$ and proving the continuity of multivariable functions.  Specifically, suppose we have $f: \Bbb R^{2} \to \Bbb R$, for example.  To prove $f$ is continuous at some $x \in \Bbb R^{2}$, we need to show for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $|| x - y || < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

My first question regarding the above is:

> Since all possible norms on $\Bbb R^{2}$ are equivalent, is it normal for us to use whichever norm on $\Bbb R^{2}$ that makes the proof above the easiest?  I have an example of a proof I came up with below to illustrate what I mean (and I would like it to be checked).

Now, my second question is about the equivalence of metrics:

> Consider two metrics $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ on some space $X$, and consider the topologies of each metric.  If we have $d_{1}(x,y) \leq c d_{2}(x,y)$ for some constant $c > 0$, does this imply the topology of $d_{1}$ is strictly finer than the topology of $d_{2}$?  I can't seem to prove this.  I guess I would need to show for any open ball around $x \in X$ in the $d_{2}$ metric, we can find an open ball around $x$ in the $d_{1}$ metric contained in the first open ball.  I think this is deceptively easy, but I haven't been able to do it.

Finally, my last question is regarding whether or not the below proof is correct:

> **Prove $f(x,y) = xy$ is continuous at each $(x_{0},y_{0}) \in \Bbb R^{2}$.**  To prove this, I will choose to use the $|| \cdot || _{\infty}$ norm on $\Bbb R^{2}$.  Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Then $|xy - x_{0}y_{0}| = |xy - xy_{0} + xy_{0} - x_{0}y_{0}| \leq |x||y - y_{0}| + |y_{0}| |x - x_{0}| \leq (|x| + |y_{0}|)||(x,y) - (x_{0},y_{0})||_{\infty}$.  If neither $|x|$ nor $|y_{0}|$ equal $0$, then choose $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{|x| + |y_{0}|}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes.

2) Let $B_i(x,r)$ be the open ball centered at $x$ of radius $r$ for the metric $d_i$. Then for all $x\in X$, for all $r>0$
$$
B_2\Bigl(x,\frac{r}{c}\Bigr)\subset B_1(x,r).
$$
What does this say about the topologies?

3) Observe that $\delta$ depends on $x$. You have to choose a bounded neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0,y_0)$ and $M$ such that $|x|\le M$ if $x\in U$.

Comment: For 2, so if $d_{1} \leq c d_{2}$, then the topology of $d_{2}$ is finer than the topology of $d_{1}$?  For some reason, I thought it was reversed.  Also, for 3, I'm confused by your answer.  Are you trying to show uniform continuity?  Is my proof correct for just regular continuity (assuming $|y_{0}| \neq 0$)?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand what you are saying for number 3.  My $\delta$ shouldn't depend on $x$.

Comment: What if I amend the proof to the following:  Suppose without loss of generality $\delta < 1$.  Then if $|| (x,y) - (x_{0}, y_{0}) ||_{\infty} < 1$, we have $|x - x_{0}| < 1$, thus $-1 + x_{0} \leq x \leq 1 + x_{0}$.  If $S = \max \{|x_{0} - 1|, |x_{0} + 1| \}$, then $|x| \leq S$, and so $|xy - x_{0}y_{0}| \leq (S + |y_{0}|)|| (x,y) - (x_{0}, y_{0})||_{\infty}$?  Here, the constant $S + |y_{0}|$ only depends on the point $(x_{0}, y_{0})$.  Then I can take $\delta = \min \{ 1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{S + |y_{0}| } \}$, and this works for all $(x_{0}, y_{0})$, even if both coordinates are zero.

Comment: That is correct. To relate it to my answer, the neighborhood $U$ would be the set of $(x,y)$ such that $\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|_\infty<1$.